# Adjust All Text and Background For A Website For Contrast (Contrast Swapper) ADA WCAG Compliance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a senior friendly website. I added a button on the top of the page to remove all background color and change it to white, and then change all text color to black to provide a nice senior friendly / visual impaired view of the site. Basically trying to achieve a contrast swapper.  I tried writing a jquery function to achieve this result. However after hours of working on this, the function I came up with is overly complicated and doesn't provide the results I hoped for as there are so many html elements to account for that could be on a page. Is there any easy way in jQuery or Javascript to select all html elements and apply a white background and black text? If there is a way I can do this in CSS that would work as well, however the results must be something I can reuse. I need to copy this functionality to 500+ sites without manually adjusting each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('html *:not(script, style, noscript)').each(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "none");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).css("color", "black");
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "none");
    $(this).css("text-shadow", "none");
});
```

I was able to use the above jQuery code to accomplish this without modifying any of my CSS. The above code changes the background to yellow and changes the text color to white. You could modify these to accomplish different behavior, for instance, white on black, black on white, black on yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Most pages add a class on `<html>` tag.
So you can make 2 css one with the class and one without.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/7RVWG/

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test3 implements Icon
{
    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int DECENDING = 1;
    public static final int ASCENDING = 2;

    protected int direction;
    protected int width = 8;
    protected int height = 8;

    public Test3(int direction)
    {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public int getIconWidth()
    {
        return width+1;
    }

    public int getIconHeight()
    {
        return height+1;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        Color bg = c.getBackground();
        Color light = bg.brighter();
        Color shade = bg.darker();

        int w = width;
        int h = height;
        int m = w / 2;
        if (direction == ASCENDING)
        {
            g.setColor(shade);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + w, y);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + m, y + h);
            g.setColor(light);
            g.drawLine(x + w, y, x + m, y + h);
        }
        if (direction == DECENDING)
        {
            g.setColor(shade);
            g.drawLine(x + m, y, x, y + h);
            g.setColor(light);
            g.drawLine(x, y + h, x + w, y + h);
            g.drawLine(x + m, y, x + w, y + h);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test3 t=new Test3(5);
        t.paintIcon(20,10,5,5);
    }
}
```